# Angular - accordion - show only active group

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using angular uib-accordion and my accordion-group is populated dynamically using ng-repeat like this

```
<uib-accordion id="customer-details">
<uib-accordion-group   ng-repeat="task in ctrl.results | toArray |     orderBy:ctrl.orderByFunction" ng-click="ctrl.select(task, $index)">
    <uib-accordion-heading >
    </uib-accordion-heading>
 <uib-accordion-group>
```

my question is how can I make this accordion to show only the active group and rest to hide completely .Also the active group needs to take the whole height of the accordion and toggling should come back to the normal state( of course toggling happens with the help of a button like + and -).

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
<ul data-ui-sref-active="active" > ... </ul>
```

Add following method in your controller:

```
$scope.opened = false;
$scope.toggle = function () {
    $scope.opened = !($scope.opened);
};
```

Then call `toggle` method in html :
`ng-click="toggle()"`

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `ng-if` directive to the repeated group element (I'm assuming each task has an `active` property):

```
<uib-accordion-group ng-repeat="task in ctrl.results | toArray | orderBy:ctrl.orderByFunction"
  ng-click="ctrl.select(task, $index)"
  ng-if="task.active">
    <uib-accordion-heading >
    </uib-accordion-heading>
<uib-accordion-group>
```

Here's the `ng-if` documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf